# If the characteristic function of $A$ is $(\lambda - 1)^n$ then $A^k$ is similar to $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, similar-matrices

Let $A \in M_n(k)$ (where $k$ is a field of characteristic $0$) and suppose the characteristic function of $A$ is $(\lambda - 1)^n$

Prove that for any positive integer $k$, $A^k$ is similar to $A$.

---

I tried to prove that $A^k$ is similar to $A$ by Jordan form, but it seems to make it more complicated.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You probably want $k\ne0$.

Comment: This is not true. E.g. $A=\pmatrix{1&1\\ 0&1}$ is not similar to $A^2=I$ over $GF(2)$. If your field is of characteristic zero, or if it is $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$, please specify as such.

Comment: @user1551 You are right. A should be considered as a matrix over a field of characteristic 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to show that $A$ and $A^k, k\ge 1$ have the same invariant factors. Each invariant factor of $A$ has the form $(x-1)^m$. Consider a cyclic subspace $W\subset F^n$ with cyclic vector $\alpha$ and minimal polynomial $(x-1)^m$. It is clear that $W$ is also $A^k$-invariant. It suffices to show that $\alpha$ is also a cyclic vector for $A^k$, namely, $W=\{f(A^k)\alpha: f\in F[x]\}$. If $f(A^k)\alpha=0$, then $(x-1)^m|f(x^k)$. Assume that $f=(x-1)^dg$ with $g(1)\ne 0$.We have $f(x^k)=(x^k-1)^dg(x^k)=(x-1)^dh^dg(x^k)$, where $h=(x^k-1)/(x-1)$. If $(h,(x-1))=1$, which is true $char(F)=0$, it should be easy to show that $d\ge m$ from $(x-1)^m|f(x^k)$. In particular, $(x-1)^m|f$. Thus the space $\{f(A^k)\alpha: f\in F[x]\}$ has dimension $m$, which implies that $W=\{f(A^k)\alpha: f\in F[x]\}$ and $A^k|_W$ also has invariant factor $(x-1)^m$. It is easy to realize the explicit similarity directly. The assumption shows that if we denote $\alpha_i=(A-I)^i\alpha$, then $\mathcal{B}=\{\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_m\}$ is a basis of $W$. The above argument shows that if we denote $\beta_i=(A^k-I)^i\alpha$ and $\mathcal{B}'=\{\beta_1,\dots,\beta_m\}$. Then $\mathcal{B}'$ is also a basis of $W$. It is easy to see that $[A]_{\mathcal{B}}=[A^k]_{\mathcal{B'}}$, which equals the Jordan block.

Comment: Does dim$\{f(A^k)\alpha:f\in F[x]\} = m$ because of $(x-1)^m$ is the minimal poly. of W? BTW thanks for your precise answer :D

Comment: Yes. Alternatively, $dim \{f(A^k)\alpha: f\in F[x]\}=m$ because the argument implies that $\mathcal{B}'$ is a basis of this space.